# Want to overwrite value on textbox when highlighted due to tabbing

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, textbox, formatting

I have a textbox that accepts only these values:

. , - $ m M k K b B and numbers

It also only accepts at most two decimal places. My problem is that after I tab off the textbox and then select it again, I am unable to type any information or overwrite whatever exists already in the textbox.

```
/// Checks if the decimal places are more than 2 and it will not allow user to keyin if its more than 2.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void txtAmount_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    string textValue = txtAmount.Text.Trim();
    if (textValue.IndexOf(".") > 0)
    {
        string[] decimalvalue = textValue.Split(new char[] { '.' });
        if (decimalvalue[1].Length >= 2)
            cancelCharacter = true;
        else
            cancelCharacter = false;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Doesn't allow the user to enter any other value other than 
/// ". , - $ m M k K b B and numbers"
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void txtAmount_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.KeyChar < 48 || e.KeyChar > 57) &&
         e.KeyChar != 46 && e.KeyChar != 36 && e.KeyChar != 36 && e.KeyChar != 32 && e.KeyChar != 44 && e.KeyChar != 8 && e.KeyChar != 45 &&
         e.KeyChar != 75 && e.KeyChar != 107 && e.KeyChar != 77 && e.KeyChar != 109 && e.KeyChar != 66 && e.KeyChar != 98)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    else if (cancelCharacter && e.KeyChar != 8 && e.KeyChar != 45 &&
             e.KeyChar != 75 && e.KeyChar != 107 && e.KeyChar != 77 && e.KeyChar != 109 && e.KeyChar != 66 && e.KeyChar != 98)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    else if (e.KeyChar == '.' && txtAmount.Text.IndexOf(".") > -1 || cancelCharacter && e.KeyChar != 8)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a tip about style and readability: Consider taking very complex if statement conditions and putting them into a function. For example, your first `if` statement could be `if IsValidCharacter(e.KeyChar)`, where the function `private void IsValidCharacterI(KeyChar character){ check conditions here }` would check for all of the conditions (with comments to know what they are actually checking). It makes it much more readable for the user.

Comment: Sure Jason. I will take your best practise advise. :) Thank you Jason. But could you please help me with correct code or correct my code please for my requirement. When I achieve some or the other issue comes :(

Comment: Perhaps if someone hasn't helped you before I get a chance. I'll be able to take a closer look at this in about 30 minutes (just had a couple minutes to burn right now).

Comment: Yups sure thank you Jason, I appreciate it :) :) Take your own time.... :) I can wait if someone else can help also... :)

Comment: You have a long explanation...is your problem now only that it accepts more than two decimal places and all the other problems are working?

Comment: Hello Brad Ok let me explain you crisp. As per above code, it doesn't allows more than 2 decimal digits. But the problem is, when I tab back to this textbox which contains a value say for example "22.32" this value is highlighted as per my requirement, but when I press any number key, it doesn't overwrites :( As because when I detect any number in textbox more than 2 digits after decimal point, I say e.handled =true as per above code. So it blocks keyin :( The user have to delete the value with backspace and then have to write. But she wants flexibility to over it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to reset your cancelCharacter flag.  Handle the `Leave` event:

```
private void txtAmount_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cancelCharacter = false;
}
```

How about this. Change to this line in you keydown event to watch for how many characters are selected:

```
if (decimalvalue[1].Length >= 2 && txtAmount.SelectionLength < 1 && 
    txtAmount.SelectionStart > textValue.IndexOf("."))
```

Comment: I am sorry Brad, I tried that already but dint work :( Andif I reset the flag in keydown when highlted like if(txtAmount.HideSelection) then I am resetting but on which case it allows more than 2 digits after decimal.  So I see only either of these works :( I want these both simultaneously :( Really it irritates me :(

Comment: @Divine, ah, yes, I see that when the textBox contains two decimal places and you hit any key, it sets your flag and then you're doomed. I think you may have to add a call to `txtAmount.SelectionStart` to determine where you are are what is selected. Then, you can either let cancelCharacter go to false or somehow overwrite the characters (maybe delete the characters selected or at the caret).

Comment: Brad - You are God :) Saved me really and my business user will appreciate me :) Thanks so much sir :) Really appreciate who are great by thoughts and humble and kind enough and simple in nature like you, my hearty wishes to you to do good always :) :) Cheers mate :)

Comment: @Divine, made more more improvement. See my edit in case you need it.

Comment: HI Brad, thank you, I appreciate your kind help, but I dint really understood how it enhances or makes it better :( I am being silly, sorry... If you have sometime, I will be happy to understand it from you :) Cheers

Comment: Hi Brad, thank you, somehow I got a clue on what you have did. Thank you Brad :) Cheers........ And your first help is in production now :) They are happy about it and me too :) Thank you so much my dear friend :)

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions were invented to handle this exact problem. [Use them](http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1). Based on your requirements, you can check for the exact input with something similar to [$,-MmKkBb\d]*[.]?[\d]{0,2}

Comment: Buddy, I am really poor in understanding RE and I dont wanna take chance of implementing this and getting into production unless I am confident. I have very less time to analyze and do these changes...I just need a quick solution (Correcting few things from my above code)...which can really help me for me :(